# Shell Script: Check if the right Conda environment active or does it exist

Tags: linux, shell

I'm starting to code an installation shell script. Therefore, I want to check that I've the right Conda environment either active or it exists.
But I have some issues, every time when the right environment is active there do not detect it inside the 'if' requested.

That is my piece of code for this functionality:

```
#!/bin/bash

desired_env="gnuradio"

# Check if the desired environment exists
if conda env list | grep -q "^$desired_env "; then
    # Check if the desired environment is active
    if conda info --envs | grep -q "^\*.*$desired_env"; then
        echo "The '$desired_env' environment is currently active."
    else
        echo "Error: The '$desired_env' environment should be active."
        echo "Please activate the '$desired_env' environment using:"
        echo "conda activate $desired_env"
        read -p "Do you want to activate environment $desired_env? ([Y]/n): " choice
        if [[ "$choice" == "y" || -z "$choice" ]]; then
            conda activate $desired_env
        else
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
else
    read -p "The '$desired_env' environment does not exist. Do you want to create it? ([Y]/n): " choice
    if [[ "$choice" == "y" || -z "$choice" ]]; then
        conda create -n $desired_env
        echo "The '$desired_env' environment has been created. Please activate it using:"
        echo "conda activate $desired_env"
    else
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

And also some further information from my terminal, where you can see that I'm already had the right environment activated:

```
(gnuradio) X@X:~/Documents/Temp$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                     /home/X/miniconda3
gnuradio              *  /home/X/miniconda3/envs/gnuradio
tf                       /home/X/miniconda3/envs/tf

(gnuradio) X@X:~/Dokumente/Temp$ bash test.sh 
The 'gnuradio' environment does not exist. Do you want to create it? ([Y]/n):
```

Maybe someone had some ideas to fix that problem.
Thank u!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it myself, for other people here's my solution, which works pretty well.

```
#!/bin/bash

desired_env="gnuradio"

# Check if the desired environment exists in the list of environments
if conda env list | grep -q "\b$desired_env\b"; then
    # Check if the desired environment is active using conda info --envs
    if conda info --envs | grep -q "^\s*$desired_env\b"; then
        echo "Error: The '$desired_env' environment should be active."
        echo "Please activate the '$desired_env' environment using:"
        echo "conda activate $desired_env"
        read -p "Do you want to activate environment $desired_env? ([Y]/n): " choice
        if [[ "$choice" == "y" || -z "$choice" ]]; then
            # Either you change it manually or use 'source' instead of 'bash' *.sh
            source /home/X/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
            conda activate $desired_env
        else
            exit 1
        fi
    else
         echo "The '$desired_env' environment is currently active."
    fi
else
    read -p "The '$desired_env' environment does not exist. Do you want to create it? ([Y]/n): " choice
    if [[ ${choice:-y} == y ]]; then
        conda create -n $desired_env
        echo "The '$desired_env' environment has been created. Please activate it using:"
        echo "conda activate $desired_env"
    else
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Checking for word boundaries by \b is not guaranteed to be understood by plain grep, and I suggest that you also specify the -E flag for portability. Also the last[[  `if` can be written simpler as `if [[ ${choice:-y} == y ]]; then `

Comment: @user1934428 thank you so much for your hind :-). I just edit it.